# Git push to new repo from existing repo main/master branch --> can this be done in GitHub desktop?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to working with GitHub.  I am setting up 2 remote repositories following the structure from this tutorial:

https://medium.com/fuzzy-code/git-push-to-new-repo-from-existing-repos-branch-acb8bef3f7be

This code works to push the main branch of one repo to a new repo.

$ git push <remote_name> <remote_repo_branch>

Can I execute this using GitHub Desktop?

Comment: All that command does is push the branch you're currently on, locally, to the remote you specify. I'm sure it's possible with Desktop, you'd just have to pull the first branch first (just as you would with the command line).

Comment: In GitHub Desktop, `push` is called `publish`